# Why does Bitcoin-Qt not launch the program, on Mac

Tags: wallet, mac, wallet-recovery

I can't believe that I have lost my Bitcoin Wallet just because I clicked on the red spot on the window of it on my Mac. Or was this enough to loose it???

I think I have the address (does it start with a 1xxxx ?) and I have my password. 
Have I lost my wallet or is it just invisible?

When I click on the Bitcoin-QT icon in my applications folder, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the icon and quit Bitcoin-QT, then restart it. I have it on my iMac and occasionally it goes completely unresponsive. If necessary, force quit. See:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Securing_your_wallet

For instructions on backing up your wallet for future.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your version. Check out in the official site of the Wallet.

Alternatively (I'm a MAC user and that worked form me) you can delete all files (except for your wallet.dat) in wallet's temp folder (/bin/something - try googling for it) and restart it from the application manager. It should show you a warning message, click OK and you're done.

Note: it will re-download the chain, so be patient ;)